# header file include-loop and multiple definition

Tags: c++, include-guards, multiple-definition-error

I have a `util.h` containing a function which will be used in `a.h` and 'b.h', and further more, `a.h` and `b.h` will include each other in order to access some classes defined in each other.

```
//util.h

#ifndef _UTIL_H_
#define _UTIL_H_

#include <iostream>

void foo()
{
    std::cout << "foo\n";
}

#endif

//a.h, it has a a.cpp
#ifndef _A_H_
#define _A_H_

#include "util.h"
#include "b.h"

//some classes' definition

#endif

//b.h, it has a b.cpp
#ifndef _B_H_
#define _B_H_

#include "util.h"
#include "a.h"

//some classes' definition

#endif
```

My problem is that, I got `multiple definition` error for `foo`. How?

I thought the problem might be that, `a.h` includes `util.h` and `b.h`, and `b.h` includes `util.h` once again, so I got multiple def error. But it can't seem to make sense, because in `util.h` I wrote `#ifndef/#define` guards.

Anyone can give me a help, thanks.

Comment: Multiple definitions is a link-time error, and shouldn't have to do with your header files (which have declarations, not definitions). How are you compiling?

Comment: @GordonBailey, I just compile it the usual way, like `g++ main.cpp a.cpp b.cpp`.

Comment: it should be `static void foo() { /* body */ }`, if you want to put the function body in the header.

Comment: Symbols starting with an underscore and double underscore are reserved by implementation. Use something like `UTIL_H_` for the header guards.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is caused by *defining* rather than simply *declaring* `foo` inside `utils.h`

For this example, assume that we have:

**a.cpp**

```
#include "a.h"
```

**b.cpp**

```
#include "b.h"
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
#include "utils.h"


int main(){
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

After preprocessing, but before compilation, your files now look like this (this is a simplification, but you get the idea):

**a.cpp**

```
void foo()
{
    std::cout << "foo\n";
}
```

**b.cpp**

```
void foo()
{
    std::cout << "foo\n";
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
void foo()
{
    std::cout << "foo\n";
}

int main(){
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Now when you compile, you have 3 definitions of `foo` (they're all identical, but this is irrelevant). After compilation, there is no way for the linker to know which definition to pick for any given call to `foo` and so it generates an error.

Instead of defining `foo` in the header, define it in `utils.cpp` and only put a declaration in `utils.h`, e.g.

**utils.h**

```
#ifndef _UTIL_H_
#define _UTIL_H_

void foo();

#endif
```

or, alternately, declare `foo` as `static` or `inline`:

**utils.h**

```
#ifndef _UTIL_H_
#define _UTIL_H_

static void foo()
{
    std::cout << "foo\n";
}

/* OR */

inline void foo()
{
    std::cout << "foo\n";
}


#endif
```

This is something you need to do only if you want to [inline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function) your function. In this case, the compiler *needs* a definition of the function in every translation unit where it is used, as it essentially becomes a compile-time macro.

Comment: Nicely explained: +1 =)  Just a subtle point I'd make...  It's true that normally you would declare the function in a header and define it in a source file, but there are times when you might define the function in a header - and that is when providing inlined functions for speed: `inline void foo() { std::cout << "foo\n"; }`.  An utterly pointless thing to do in this case, however!

Comment: So, by `inline` the compiler will treat `foo` as `static`?